# Saving live output to file in real-time in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, mqtt

I have MQTT client which sending information to MQTT Broker (Ubuntu).
My Python script can run the command to gettint these informations:

```
import os
os.system("mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.107 -t test1 -t test2")
```

Buw how could i saving these live information into a txt file in real-time using a python ?

Comment: Why are you calling an external shell application and not using the Paho Python library to handle this all in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the fastest way would be:

```
import os 
os.system("mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.107 -t test1 -t test2| tee -a mymessages.txt")
```

Comment: And is it possible to do it but with showing outout in terminal as well ?

Comment: Did the above work? If so maybe you can consider to accept the answer for others to benefit. @Mamedov_A.